# Perl IPTables Module Installation Error

Tags: perl, cpan, perl-module, iptables

I've been trying to install the IPTables module for perl [http://metacpan.org/pod/IPTables::IPv4](http://metacpan.org/pod/IPTables%3a%3aIPv4) and I've been running into errors during installation.

I've tried installing using the CPAN in shell as well as downloading the tarball form the link above. Both installation give me errors. I am not sure how to get the dump from CPAN but what I can get is a dump of my shell when I run the MAKE file from the tarball:

```
[root@localhost IPTables-IPv4-0.98]# make
make -C libiptc/ all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/student/Downloads/IPTables-IPv4-0.98/libiptc'
gcc -o libip6tc.o -c libip6tc.c -I../include -I/usr/src/linux/include -DIPTABLES_VERSION=\"1.2.8\" -O2 -Wall
In file included from libip6tc.c:111:0:
libiptc.c: In function ‘ip6tc_init’:
libiptc.c:312:10: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 5 of ‘getsockopt’ differ in signedness
/usr/include/sys/socket.h:190:12: note: expected ‘socklen_t * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
libiptc.c: In function ‘target_name’:
libiptc.c:727:2: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
libip6tc.c: In function ‘ipv6_prefix_length’:
libip6tc.c:121:7: error: ‘const struct in6_addr’ has no member named ‘in6_u’
libip6tc.c:125:7: error: ‘const struct in6_addr’ has no member named ‘in6_u’
libip6tc.c: In function ‘dump_entry’:
libip6tc.c:201:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
make[1]: *** [libip6tc.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/student/Downloads/IPTables-IPv4-0.98/libiptc'
make: *** [libiptc/libiptc.a] Error 2
[root@localhost IPTables-IPv4-0.98]#
```

I would like to know what do I need to do so that I can install the module. Are there some dependencies that I need to install?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you realise that one's not been maintained for many years? There are some patches in the [RT queue](https://rt.cpan.org/Dist/Display.html?Name=IPTables-IPv4), but I think you're better of [trying different distros](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=iptables).

Comment: Yea, I realized its old, but I kinda need this for my course of work. Unless some alternatives are available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [cpanratings](http://cpanratings.perl.org/dist/IPTables-IPv4) and [CPAN testers reports](http://static.cpantesters.org/distro/I/IPTables-IPv4.html) for this module make me think that you're wasting your time here.

Comment: Seems like that's really the case... Thanks!