# Error installing perl module IPTables::IPv4

Tags: perl

While installing perl module `IPTables::IPv4`, I got stuck with this error:

```
make[1]: *** [libip4tc.o] Error 1 
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/.cpan/build/IPTables-IPv4-0.98/libiptc' 
make: *** [libiptc/libiptc.a] Error 2 
/usr/bin/make -- NOT OK
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Those lines of output are not the error - they are make telling you that an earlier part of the build failed.  You should have more information that proceeded those 4 lines, can you post them?

Comment: this outcome come while compiling  IPTables::IPv4 module in ubuntu 12.04 while configuration of packetfence, please follow this link for clear visualization: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649078/perl-iptables-module-installation-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with a module building, not a perl fault. The place to address that would really be with the module 'owner'.

You can find test reports:

http://static.cpantesters.org/distro/I/IPTables-IPv4.html

And module ratings:
http://cpanratings.perl.org/dist/IPTables-IPv4

This would seem to imply that this module isn't finished and working, so you're on a road to nowhere. You may need to seek alternatives. (Or roll up your sleeves and take on the challenge of writing one yourself).

Comment: Issue was with version, its solved